# Retrieving REAL value from SQLite table

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to build a converter-like app between different measurement units. At the moment, I am using SQLite and I've got a table that includes different units alongside corresponding rates.

Inside my app I've got the following functions to retrieve rate values depending on selected units:

```
+(float)rateFrom:(NSString *)from to:(NSString *)to{
    if (sqlite3_open([sqlPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT %@ FROM Units WHERE code = '%@'", to, from] UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            return (float)sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 0);
        }
    }
    else{
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The problem is that the return rate is 0.00

I've tried the constructed query directly on my Terminal window and returns correct values

I've tried `NSNumber` and `initWithFloat:` with no success too.

Could anyone explain me what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be sure you understand [SQLite data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and "type affinity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never actually executing the query. `sqlite3_prepare_v2` "compiles" the query, but doesn't actually *run* it. You're probably going to want to call `sqlite3_step` to actually execute the query.  You're also not calling `sqlite3_finalize` on your compiled statement, so you're also leaking memory with this code.  This might help:

```
+ (float)rateFrom:(NSString *)from to:(NSString *)to
{
    float retVal = -1;
    if (sqlite3_open([sqlPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT %@ FROM Units WHERE code = '%@'", to, from] UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK && 
           sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            retVal = (float)sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 0);
        }
        if (selectstmt) {
            sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        database = NULL;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Also, while were at it, if the strings in `to` and `from` come from user input, you probably don't want to use them literally in queries, as this is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

You could also consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which is a nice Objective-C wrapper for the SQLite API.

Comment: Thank you! Function returns the correct results now. Thank you for quick reply. So, apart from finalize (didn't know that as is my first time that I am working with SQLite), my mistake was the not use of sqlite3_step()?
Thank you for the provided link too.

Comment: You also need to close the database after using it if you open it each time. The current code currently (and needlessly) closes the database only if it can't be open.

Comment: Yes, the principal issue preventing you from getting the value you expected was the absence of `sqlite3_step`. And rmaddy is right too.